# How to write a static method in Mongoose that gets all documents?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Mongoose. I wrote a statics method and a instance method for a Mongoose schema named 'questionSchema' and exported it like so:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
    ...
})

questionSchema.methods.createQuestion = function(){
    return this.save(function(err){
        if(err){ 
            return  err
        };
        return 'Saved the question';
    });
};

questionSchema.statics.getAllQ = function(){
    return this.find({}, function(err, res){
        if(err){ 
            return  err
        };
        return res;
    });
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema)
```

Then in a route in my Node/Express server, I imported the it as a model, and tried calling the static method, which should return all the documents under the Question model:

```
const Question = require('../models/question.js');

...

router.post('/qcrud/submit', (req, res) => {
    let reqBody = req.body;

    var newQuestion = new Question({reqBody});    
    newQuestion.createQuestion();
})

router.get('/qcrud/getAll',(req, res) => {
    let qArr = Question.getAllQ()
    res.send(qArr);
});
```

However, it returns a Query object, not an array like I expected. I looked around and saw on MDN that

> 'If you don't specify a callback then the API will return a variable
>   of type Query.'

I did specify a callback, but still got the Query object. First of all, am I using my static and instance methods right? Are the documents even saving? And how do I access the array documents saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Node 8.x you can utilize [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

This way your code will look more synchronous:

```
questionSchema.statics.getAllQ = async () => {
    return await this.find({});
}

router.get('/qcrud/getAll',async (req, res) => {
    let qArr = await Question.getAllQ();
    res.send(qArr);
});
```

You can find a really nice article that is explaining how to use `Mongoose` with async/await [here](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/cleaner-code-in-nodejs-with-async-await-mongoose-calls-example).

Comment: If this returns an empty array [ ] for me, does this mean that my documents haven't been saved? Do I need to then use async await for saving too?

Comment: Well that means that your method for saving is not working correctly, because there is nothing in database. You should probably try to check that method. On link that I've included in answer you have example how can you use await/async with `save`

Comment: But it's explicitly written [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) to not declare statics using ES6 arrow functions : "Do not declare statics using ES6 arrow functions (=>). Arrow functions explicitly prevent binding this, so the above examples will not work because of the value of this."